# how to handle data from text editors store in database and later display

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I use TinyMce for project. when i get the text from the user, i do the following with PHP

- to handle the html inputs i use htmlspecialchars() mysql_real_escape_string() functions available on php to make it ready for storage in database.
- i then store it in the database.

Now how do i safely insert, retrieve and display html data.
One big challenge is to get only the text, without the html and make it available as the 
Meta description of the page.

In a nutshell i want to

- Get data from text editor
- format and store in database
- retrieve from database
- get clean version without html tags
- get html version and display on page

Comment: How about saving the data in 2 separate fields in your database: 1 with HTML and other without. Some Editors have the option to strip HTML before saving. On a sidenote: if the given input can be a long text (an entire page for example) I would not recommend putting all of it as Meta Description and would rather suggest using a separate textarea for the user to input a custom Meta description.

Comment: @Dark that would be good. could you give me examples of editors that can strip html before saving ??

Comment: @DarkAshelin: If you have a save way to change format from html to non html, never add the data to the database twice. This is a redundancy you do not want.

Comment: @TobiasKun If you change the format after retrieving from the database, UDcreate will have to do it himself in PHP. If the Editor has a format-changing option built-in, it may just be easier for him to use that.

Comment: @DarkAshelin: That's right. But i would never store the so received data in the database. I would then use the regexp provided by the editor to do it myself in php. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags()

Refer:http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use [html2text](http://www.chuggnutt.com/html2text!) class.

```
<?php
require_once(‘class.html2text.inc’);
$html = ‘Sample string with HTML code in it’;
$h2t =& new html2text($html);
$text = $h2t->get_text();
$h2t->print_text();
?>
```